# Mysql, retrieve students who haven't received a request from me

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently logged in as the first student. I want to retrieve a list of the students I did not send a request to yet. I also want to retrieve a list of students I sent a request to.

Both `sender_id` and `Rec_id` are foreign keys referencing to `Students.id`.

[DB schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK0Up.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Souleiman and welcome to stackoverflow! Your question is not quite clear, you say that `sender_id` and `Rec_id` in `requestts` are both referencing to `students`, but you can't see to which field exactly. Your `requestts` table contains different entries in these fields.

Next time you should post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE students` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE requestts` and a little INSERT statement for the data. Furthermore it would be nice if you would explain the relations and show what you have already tried (see Barmars comment).

I suppose that the relevant foreign key in requestts is `Rec_id`, so you could try this query:

```
SELECT s.email FROM students s WHERE s.id NOT IN
(SELECT Rec_id FROM requestts WHERE Rec_id = s.id);
```

Hope this helps. Have fun learning SQL!